# Defining the difference of compositions in the Wolfram Language

Tags: symbolic-math, wolfram-language

I've been trying to define a function `compdiff` on the Wolfram Language that takes two mathematical expressions `f` and `g` and a variable `x` as input and outputs the difference of their compositions `f[g[x]]-g[f[x]]` (a sort of commutator if you are into abstract algebra).

For example: `compdiff[x^2,x+1,x] = (x+1)^2-(x^2+1)`.

I've tried with

```
compdiff[f_,g_,x_]:= Composition[f,g][x]-Composition[g,f][x]
```

and

```
compdiff[f_,g_,x_]:= f @* g @ x-g @* f @ x
```

but when I input

```
compdiff[x^2,x+1,x]
```

it outputs

```
(x^2)[(1 + x)[x]] - (1 + x)[(x^2)[x]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use functions instead of expressions. For example:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x+1
```

Then compdiff[f, g, x] will work:

```
In[398]:= compdiff[f,g,x]
Out[398]= -1-x^2+(1+x)^2
```

Alternatively, you could use pure functions, as in:

```
In[399]:= compdiff[#^2&,#+1&,x]
Out[399]= -1-x^2+(1+x)^2
```